# Collections.sort() is not working across all members

Tags: java, sorting, java-7

I am trying to sort a list using Collections.sort() and noticing notice all the members are being sorted:

Here is my input, a print out of the .compareTo() insides, and the output:

```
5 4 3 2 1     // Original
me = 4: o = 5 // A printout at each entry into .compareTo()
me = 3: o = 4
me = 3: o = 5
me = 2: o = 5
me = 2: o = 3
me = 1: o = 3
me = 1: o = 2
4 5 3 2 1     // Final output (1 should be at the beginning though)
```

My rules for sorting are:

```
1<4
3<2
4<5
```

My implementation is:

```
        List<Task> tasks = new TaskList();
        Task.create(tasks); // creates a list 5 4 3 2 1 
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.next();
            Task.rules.add(line); // address the rules such as "1<4"
        }
        System.out.println(tasks);
        Collections.sort(tasks);
```

And the compareTo() implementation:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        int me = id;
        int o = ((Task) arg0).id;
        System.out.println("me = " + me + ": o = " + o);
        for (String s : rules) { // rules is an array of strings "1<4" etc
            int left = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, 1));
            int right = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(2));
            char op = s.charAt(1);

            boolean meLeft = left == me;
            boolean oLeft = left == o;
            boolean meRight = right == me;
            boolean oRight = right == o;

            if (meLeft && oRight) {
                if (op == '<') { // me < other
                    return -1;
                } else
                    return 1;
            } else if (oLeft && meRight) {
                if (op == '<') {// other < me
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

As you can see from the "me = M, o = O" at the top, the Collections.sort() is not iterating through all the members of the list!

I would expect the following to show for each member "me" all the other members "o" to be compared, so I'd expected that list at the top of this question to be much longer! I believe its size should be N^2...

Comment: sorting uses qsort which does not compare n^2 times, it uses NlogN comparisons only

Comment: compareTo doesn't need to be called for all combinations. If it knows that A < B and B < C then it knows, that A < C without comparing them.

Comment: Your ordering isn't transitive.  But the contract for `compareTo` requires transitivity.

Comment: Transitivity means that if 1<4 and 4<5 then 1<5. But 1<5 isn't one of your rules. If a `compareTo` method isn't transitive, all bets are off as to what `sort` does.

Comment: Outside of your rules everything is equal (you will not find the match and return 0).

Comment: @Lashane, how to make sure Collections.sort is using the N^2 type of soring?

Comment: @E.S. it is impossible

Comment: Okay, so forget Collections.sort()... is there another function that will use your compareTo() method to do a full sort, N^2, etc.

Comment: You don't _want_ your sort algorithm to be N^2. Just make your rules complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method breaks the contract for that method in two ways.

1) Transitivity says that if `x.compareTo(y) > 0` and `y.compareTo(z) > 0` then `x.compareTo(z) > 0`. Your method breaks this because `5 > 4` and `4 > 1`, but `5>1` is not one of your rules.

2) `compareTo` must also meet the condition that if `x.compareTo(y) == 0` then `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))` for all `z`. Your method breaks this because `5.compareTo(1) == 0`, whereas `5.compareTo(4)` and `1.compareTo(4)` have opposite signs.

If you don't meet the contract for `compareTo`, the results of `sort` are unpredictable. However in your case, we can see what's going on. 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 *is* in order because `4 < 5 = 3 < 2 = 1`. (I am using `=` to mean the `compareTo` method returns 0). There are no `>` signs in that chain, so there is no reason to continue sorting.

If you want 1 to come to the front, in addition to making your `compareTo` method meet the two conditions above, you will have to add at least one rule involving something from [1, 4, 5] and something from [2, 3]. As long as there is no such rule, there is no reason for the 1 at the end to move past the 2 and the 3.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I understand that it seems to break the contract as you specified. However, the .compareTo() function would work perfectly fine, I believe, in a non-quickSort algorithm. I wonder there a basic-sort O(N^2) that can be applied on compareTo() ?

Comment: I don't think there is. I really like your approach to writing a `compareTo` method by specifying basic rules, so I would persevere with it. What you can do is write two nested loops (both iterating over your rules). If you find a rule a<b and a rule b<c you can add a new rule a<c. This is a bit complicated because whenever you add a rule you'd have start iterating over the nested loops all over again. You can make it work though.